# Allocating a new object in a header file

Tags: c++

I came across this pattern in my codebase while debugging a null pointer problem:

```
#include <iostream>                                   

class Foo {                                           
  public:                                             
    Foo() {                                           
      std::cout << "In Foo constructor." << std::endl;
    };                                                
};                                                    

static const Foo* DEFAULT_FOO(new Foo);
```

It occurred to me this might be a bad idea, and moving this constant initialization to a cpp file instead of a header fixed my problem.

My question is, what exactly is happening here, and why is it allowed in the first place?

As I understand it, this allocates an object on the heap before the main function is called, and the backtrace from inside that constructor shows a bunch of scary-looking internal stuff. Worse, when there are multiple compilation units, each compilation unit gets its own copy of this header, and therefore its own version of DEFAULT_FOO; I see many copies of "In Foo constructor" in the program output before any output from main.

Somehow in my codebase, one object's copy of the DEFAULT_FOO pointer came out null, and moving initialization of DEFAULT_FOO to a cpp file fixed this. What gives?

Comment: @M.M I don't understand the request

Comment: Sorry, I assumed all-caps indicated this was a macro defined elsewhere

Comment: Ah, I habitually make consts all-caps by convention picked up from other languages. Is the convention in c++ to only make macros all-caps?

Answer (score 1):

Your second to last paragraph is spot on and a good overview why this is a bad idea.

Your last paragraph, I don't know. As the pointer value itself is not constant, it could be messed up by anything in the rest of your code.

One thing you missed - the object is also leaked. Although this isn't a big deal as it only needs to be deleted when the program is shutting down, should any important stuff need to be called in the destructor, it will be skipped (unless there is external code to delete the pointer, which is even messier).

Therefore you should either wrap it in a smart pointer, or just make it a regular object and not allocated dynamically, or check out the singleton pattern.

Comment: Excellent point about the leak, I hadn't considered that. In the original code it was actually a boost::shared_ptr<Foo>, but I figured Foo* would illustrate the question more clearly.

Comment: Ah, upon consideration, I think I should have written the question as `static Foo* const`, since it was `const boost::shared_ptr<Foo>` in my source.

Comment: @JamesBailey Making a shared pointer to an object that will live the entire lifetime of the program is even more strange.

Comment: I fail to see the need for heap allocation to begin with. Why not simply extern const FOO DefaultFoo?

Comment: It's so that objects that have a `boost::shared_ptr<Foo>` member can be initialized with `DEFAULT_FOO`. The objects themselves have Foo pointers instead of Foo values to get the polymorphism of `FooImplA` and `FooImplB`.

Answer (score 1):

Your are correct that this bad code. First of all, you should not declare static variables in headers - it makes no sense whatsover, since header is included into every cpp file! So what you end up is multiple copies of different DEFAULT_FOO! (since every cpp file sees it as static, it is creating it's own local symbol). This is why you do not see any linking errors.

So declare your variables in header file (with extern), define them in cpp file, keep calm and continue learning.

Comment: I like the keep calm part

Answer (score 0):

When a compilation unit `#include`'s a file, it basically just inserts the text from the header into the compilation unit.  So then in your original version, each compilation unit will include the line:

```
static const Foo* DEFAULT_FOO(new Foo);
```

Thus each one will allocation/construct a `Foo` object.

Moving that line into a cpp file means that only one compilation unit will actually create the object.